# R rbind during loop

Tags: r, loops, rbind

This code works for everything... except the rbind part at the end. I want to take the results from the loop and combine them into one forecast data frame. I tried to create an empty temp data frame (I am forecasting 12 quarters) but I get a "not equally sized" error.

Can someone help me out? I'm almost there :-)

```
# Create actual data frame
Data_act <- subset(Data,Data$Type=="Actual")

# Create forecast frame with descriptive columns
Data_fc <- subset(Data[1:5],Data$Type=="Forecast")

# Create empty data frame for forecast results
Data_fc2 <- subset(Data[,6:9],Data$Type=="Forecast")
Data_fc2 <- Data_fc2[1:12,]
Data_fc3 <- Data_fc2 # temp table for loop

# Create list of unique forecast names
UniqueList <- unique(Data_act$forecast_name)

# Loop through unique list of forecast names
for(i in 1:length(UniqueList)){

    # Subset data for forecast name
    df <- subset(Data_act,Data_act$forecast_name==UniqueList[i])

    # Create time series objects
    dftsunits <- ts(df$Units,start = c(2015,1),frequency = 4)
    dftsasp <- ts(df$ASP,start = c(2015,1),frequency = 4)

    # Train forecasting models (Holt-Winters and ARIMA)
    FC_Units_HW <- hw(dftsunits,h=12)
    FC_Units_Arima <- auto.arima(dftsunits,lambda = 0) #lambda = 0 prevents     negative forecasts
    FC_ASP_HW <- hw(dftsasp,h=12)
    FC_ASP_Arima <- auto.arima(dftsasp,lambda = 0)

    # Forecast models for 12 quarters
    FC_Units_HW2 <- forecast(FC_Units_HW,h=12)
    FC_Units_Arima2 <- forecast(FC_Units_Arima,h=12)
    FC_ASP_HW2 <- forecast(FC_ASP_HW,h=12)
    FC_ASP_Arima2 <- forecast(FC_ASP_Arima,h=12)

    # Save results
    Data_fc3$Units_HW <- FC_Units_HW2$mean
    Data_fc3$Units_ARIMA <- FC_Units_Arima2$mean
    Data_fc3$ASP_HW <- FC_ASP_HW2$mean
    Data_fc3$ASP_ARIMA <- FC_ASP_Arima2$mean

    # Add results to master result data frame
    Data_fc2 <= rbind(Data_fc2,Data_fc3)
}
```

Comment: It is advised to never use `rbind` inside a loop. It can lead to quadratic copying. See Patrick Burns' [R Inferno - Circle 2: Growing Objects](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiaqb_xn6LgAhUBSa0KHTOcAcoQ5OUBMAh6BAgHEAE&usg=AOvVaw3ccYVJrqViLKxffdLT6tdj).

Comment: Thanks...that article is WAY over my head.  I'm a newbie to R but did a lot of VBA coding so I am writing like it would work in Excel.  Any thoughts on how to proceed?

Comment: I'm new here too :-)

Comment: The problem with your `rbind` line is that you use "less than or equal to" `<=` instead of "assignment" `<-` :)  ...but as others say `rbind` in a for loop is really inefficient

Comment: D'OH!!  Coding is a bitch :-).  My code works now...and my script only takes a few seconds... but I would LOVE if someone can give me tips on how to be more efficient in the future.

Comment: The R Inferno (linked above) is an excellent resource for this. Just read Circle 2, Growing Objects. It's just over 4 pages long (including a picture), and it will really help you understand things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is effective.  I would love to know how to make it more efficient.  I need to append the forecasts after the actuals.

```
# Create actual data frame
Data_act <- subset(Data,Data$Type=="Actual")

# Create forecast frame with descriptive columns
Data_fc <- subset(Data[1:5],Data$Type=="Forecast")

# Create empty data frame for forecast results
Data_fc2 <- subset(Data[,6:9],Data$Type=="Forecast")
Data_fc2 <- Data_fc2[1:12,]
Data_fc3 <- Data_fc2 # temp table for loop

# Create list of unique forecast names
UniqueList <- unique(Data_act$forecast_name)

# Loop through unique list of forecast names and run time series
for(i in 1:length(UniqueList)){

    # Subset data for forecast name
    df <- subset(Data_act,Data_act$forecast_name==UniqueList[i])

    # Create time series objects
    dftsunits <- ts(df$Units,start = c(2015,1),frequency = 4)
    dftsasp <- ts(df$ASP,start = c(2015,1),frequency = 4)

    # Train forecasting models (Holt-Winters and ARIMA)
    FC_Units_HW <- hw(dftsunits,h=12)
    FC_Units_Arima <- auto.arima(dftsunits,lambda = 0) #lambda = 0 prevents negative forecasts
    FC_ASP_HW <- hw(dftsasp,h=12)
    FC_ASP_Arima <- auto.arima(dftsasp,lambda = 0)

    # Forecast models for 12 quarters
    FC_Units_HW2 <- forecast(FC_Units_HW,h=12)
    FC_Units_Arima2 <- forecast(FC_Units_Arima,h=12)
    FC_ASP_HW2 <- forecast(FC_ASP_HW,h=12)
    FC_ASP_Arima2 <- forecast(FC_ASP_Arima,h=12)

    # Save results
    Data_fc3$Units_HW <- FC_Units_HW2$mean
    Data_fc3$Units_ARIMA <- FC_Units_Arima2$mean
    Data_fc3$ASP_HW <- FC_ASP_HW2$mean
    Data_fc3$ASP_ARIMA <- FC_ASP_Arima2$mean

    # Add results to master result data frame
    Data_fc2 <- rbind(Data_fc2,Data_fc3)
}

Data_fc2 <- na.omit(Data_fc2)# Remove original 12 empty rows
Data_fc <- cbind(Data_fc,Data_fc2)
Data_Final <- rbind(Data_act,Data_fc)
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to fix this would be instead of initialising your empty dataframe outside the loop (i.e. lines 7-10), within the loop include an if statement to check if it's the first iteration (i.e. if i == 1). If it is - don't do the rbind, but if not, do the rbind. Something like this might work:

```
if (i == 1) {
data_out <- Data_fc3
} else {
data_out <- rbind(data_out, Data_fc2)
}
```

Comment: PS I'm new here too!

Comment: Is there a way for you to use `ifelse` in this? `ifelse` has some speed gains(sometimes)

Comment: Thank you, Alexandra!  I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Gregor, for finding my syntax error!  While my code if effective now...it is still horribly inefficient.  I would love to know what the best way to combine data in a loop is.

Cheers!

```
Data_fc2 <- rbind(Data_fc2,Data_fc3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider `by` to subset your data by the unique groupings to build a **list** of data frames to `rbind` **once** outside the loop. Below assigned a generalized user-defined method that inputs and outputs the subsetted data frame and passes it into `by`:

```
# Create actual data frame
Data_act <- subset(Data, Type=="Actual")

# Create empty data frame for forecast results 
Data_fc <- subset(Data[1:12,6:9], Type=="Forecast")

# GENERALIZED METHOD
proc_forecast <- function(sub_df) {    
    # Create time series objects
    dftsunits <- ts(sub_df$Units, start = c(2015,1), frequency = 4)
    dftsasp <- ts(sub_df$ASP, start = c(2015,1), frequency = 4)

    # Train forecasting models (Holt-Winters and ARIMA)
    FC_Units_HW <- hw(dftsunits, h=12)
    FC_Units_Arima <- auto.arima(dftsunits, lambda = 0)  
    FC_ASP_HW <- hw(dftsasp, h=12)
    FC_ASP_Arima <- auto.arima(dftsasp, lambda = 0)

    # Forecast models for 12 quarters and save results to new columns
    sub_df <- within(Data_fc, {
                   Units_HW <- forecast(FC_Units_HW, h=12)$mean
                   Units_ARIMA <- forecast(FC_Units_Arima, h=12)$mean
                   ASP_HW <- forecast(FC_ASP_HW, h=12)$mean
                   ASP_ARIMA <- forecast(FC_ASP_Arima, h=12)$mean
              })    
    return(sub_df)
}

# BY CALL
df_list <- by(Data_act, Data_act$forecast_name, proc_forecast)

# FINAL DF BUILD
final_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
final_df <- cbind(subset(Data[1:5], Type=="Forecast"), final_df)
final_df <- rbind(Data_act, final_df)
```

Comment: Thanks Parfait!!  I'll check this out!  I'll have to research what a By call is :-)

Comment: the By_Call gave me a "replacement element 1 has 12 rows, need 16" error.  The ts objects are 16 quarters but I am forecasting 12.  I guess I could forecast 16.

Comment: It's the ARIMA models that are the problem

Comment: Scratch that.  I tried making the horizons 16.  When I look in the df_list, it is putting the forecasts next to the actuals.  That is why it needs 16.  I need them to go after the actuals.

Comment: See update saving forecast values to the empty *Data_fc3* with each `by` iteration.

Comment: Thanks again, Parfait!  I'll definitely incorporate this methodology in future coding.  Full transparency though, your code took the runtime down from 10 seconds to 9.5.  I know that adds up when the dataset is enormous.

Comment: Parfait...probably the reason your code is not as fast is because it is generating way too much data somehow.  The end table should be 1176 rows and yours is over 21,000.  Don't waste any more time on this...because I need to move on to other things.  Thanks again!